# Step detector sensor in android not working

Tags: android, android-sensors

I've been trying to add the step detector sensor in my app and when I do this I don't seem to get the right values.

A brief overview of what my code does, my code uses the accelerometer and the step detector (among other sensors) and writes the result in a file.

The app writes the data in the file, but I can't seem to get the right values for the step detector. I only get 0, and as I read in the android documentation, 0 means that a step has not been detected. But I tried my app by taking steps, so 1's would be the correct value to obtain.

Here's my onSensorChanged code:

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

most of android Versions are not support step detector/counter API.
Basically step detector filter the accelerometer sensor data.

****My Approach ****

- Collect sensor data
- Filter it (low pass/high pass or rounded the values)
- Detect the general  step pattern or check for highest values
- model the pattern
- implement in your app

if you need farther help feel free to ask..